# duplicate results with array of array in class

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new with java and I need to save the content of a stack of objects into an array which will have an array attribute and also the array attribute has an array attribute I know it kind complicated but I need to do that because it's looks like a table. Anyway, this is my code

```
//First class
     public static class classA //inner
              { public char sy;
                public ArrayList <Integer> arrystateA;
                public classA()
               { sy='0';
                 arrystateA= new ArrayList <Integer>();} }

//The second class 

     public static  class ArrayofclassA// meddile
              { int num;
                public ArrayList <classA> arrystateB;  
                public ArrayofclassA()
              {    arrystateB=new ArrayList < classA>();
                   num=-1;}
                 public void creatrans(classA z)
                  { arrystateB.add(z);
                } }
```

and this the main code

```
classA temp2=new classA();
                    ArrayofclassA temp3 = new ArrayofclassA();
                  ArrayList<ArrayofclassA> NFAtranstable=new ArrayList<ArrayofclassA>();



                       while(!reslt.empty()){
                           temp=reslt.pop();
                          for (int i=0;i<NFAtranstable.size();i++)
                           {temp3=NFAtranstable.get(i);
                              if (temp3.num==temp.s_to)
                              {
                                  if(temp3.arrystateB.get(i).sy==temp.t_sym)
                                  {
                                    temp3.arrystateB.get(i).arrystateA.add(temp.s_to);  
                                     match=true;


                                  }else
                                      {temp2.sy=temp.t_sym;temp2.arrystateA.add(temp.s_to);
                                      temp3.creatrans(temp2);

                                      match=true;

                                      }
                                  }
                              }

                           if(!match)
                           {

                               temp2.sy=temp.t_sym;
                               temp2.arrystateA.add(temp.s_to);
                               temp3.num=temp.s_from;
                              temp3.arrystateB.add(temp2);
                               NFAtranstable.add(temp3);




                           }
                           match=false;
                           }



                       for(int i=0;i<NFAtranstable.size();i++)
                           { 
                           System.out.print(NFAtranstable.get(i).num+"      "); 
                           for(int j=0;j<NFAtranstable.get(i).arrystateB.size();j++)
                           {
                              System.out.println(NFAtranstable.get(i).arrystateB.get(j).sy+"      ");

                             for(int k=0;k<NFAtranstable.get(i).arrystateB.get(j).arrystateA.size();k++)
                               {
                                   System.out.print(NFAtranstable.get(i).arrystateB.get(j).arrystateA.get(k));
                               }
                           }
                     }
               }
```

the problem that when I print the content of the array 'NFAtranstable' it's gives me duplicate results like it just save the same valus, it's been about 8 hours and I couldn't find the problem =(

Comment: this is some poorly written code, can you refactor it to look more readable ? Otherwise it would be hard to analyse it.

Comment: Not able to read code properly. But based on your last statement, it seems like your NFAtrastable has all the content referenced to same list. So can you try moving your `ArrayofclassA temp3 = new ArrayofclassA();` inside your while loop and see if it helps